# python for read file operation

Tags: python

I am working on python. I have created file demofile.txt. from this link https://indiankanoon.org/doc/982107/ I have copied the text and paste it in demofile.txt. Now I want to read the file and in that file there are the sentence like "in State of Haryana v. Subhash Chander Marwaha and Others," in blue color. I want output like this from that file. and the condition is it start with letter 'in' and in between there should be letter 'v.' and end with ','

In some case sentence start with letter 'in' and end with ',' and in some case not. for example in this case:
"The Judgment of the Court was delivered by Sharma, j. This appeal was earlier heared by a Division Bench and was referred to a Constitution Bench for examining the question whether a candidate whose name appears in the merit list on the basis of a competitive examination, acquires indefeasible right of appointment as a Government servant if a vacancy exists. Reference was made to the decision **in State of Haryana v. Subhash Chander Marwaha and Others,** [1974] 1 SCR 165;** Miss Neelima Shangla, Ph.D.v. State of Haryana and Others,** [1986] 4 SCC 268 and **Jitendra Kumar and Others v. State of Punjab and Others.** [1985] 1SCR"

So in this case the output will be like this **"in State of Haryana v. Subhash Chander Marwaha and Others,[1974] 1 SCR 165; Miss Neelima Shangla, Ph.D.v. State of Haryana and Others, [1986] 4 SCC 268 and Jitendra Kumar and Others v. State of Punjab and Others."**

And in another case for example:
"8. **In State of Haryana v. Subhash Chander Marwaha and Others,** (supra) 15 vacancies of Subordinate Judges were advertised, and out of the selection list only 7, who had secured more than 55% marks, were appointed, although under the relevant rules the eligibility condition required only 45% marks. Since the High Court had recommended earlier, to the Punjab Government that only the candidates securing 55% marks or more should be appointed as Subordinate Judges, the other candidates included in the select list were not appointed. They filed a writ petition before the High Court claiming a right of being appointed on the ground that vacancies existed and they were qualified and were found suitable. The writ application was allowed. While reversing the decision of the High Court, it was observed by this Court that it was open to the Government to decide how MANY appointments should be made and although the High Court had appreciated the position correctly, it had ``somehow persuaded itself to spell out a right in the candidates because in fact there were 15 vacancies''. It was expressly ruled that the existence of vacancies does not give a legal right to a selected candidate. Similarly, the claim of some of the candidates selected for appointment, who were petitioners **in Jitendra Kumar and Others v. State of Punjab and Others,** was turned down holding that it was open to the Government to decide how many appointments would be made. The plea of arbitrariness was rejected in view of the facts of the case and it was had that the candi-"

So in this case the output should be **"In State of Haryana v. Subhash Chander Marwaha and Others,"** **"in Jitendra Kumar and Others v. State of Punjab and Others,"**

I have written a code like this. But I am not getting proper expection output.

```
# # Open the file in read mode
file_path = 'demofile.txt'
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # Read the contents of the file
    text = file.read().strip().lower()


    # Start searching for the case name
    start_index = 0
    closest_index = -1
    while True:
        # Find the position of "v."
        start_index = text.find("v.", start_index)
        # print(f"Start: {start_index}")

        if start_index == -1:
            break  # Exit the loop if no more occurrences are found

        # Find the position of the closest "in" before "v."
        closest_in_index = text.rfind("in ", 0, start_index)
        # print(f"closest_in_index: {closest_in_index}")


        if closest_in_index != -1 and (closest_index == -1 or closest_in_index > closest_index):
            closest_index = closest_in_index
            # print(f"closest_index: {closest_index}")

        # Find the position of ","
        end_index = text.index(",", start_index)
        # print(f"End: {end_index}")

        # Extract the desired text
        desired_text = text[closest_index:end_index]

        # Trim any leading/trailing spaces
        desired_text = desired_text.strip()

        # Print the desired text
        if start_index - closest_index < 30:
            print(desired_text)

        # Update the start index to continue searching from the next position
        start_index = end_index + 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please keep in mind that we do not [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) code for you here. Instead, we answer **questions** about what you can't understand *after finding* a problem (*one* problem). "I have written a code like this. But I am not getting proper expection output." What output do you get? How is that different from what you want? What is in the file to start? Did you try to figure out what happens, step by step, when the code is running? Where does it start to do something different from what you expect?

Comment: Hi, @KarlKnechtel. Expecting  output is:
in State of Haryana v. Subhash Chander Marwaha and Others,[1974] 1 SCR 165; Miss Neelima Shangla, Ph.D.v. State of Haryana and Others, [1986] 4 SCC 268 and Jitendra Kumar and Others v. State of Punjab and Others.
In State of Haryana v. Subhash Chander Marwaha and Others," "in Jitendra Kumar and Others v. State of Punjab and Others,

Comment: Have you considered using a regular expression (re module)?

Comment: Hi @DarkKnight. No